# How to indicate missing translation in a string.xml file in Android

Tags: android, string, locale

I have 2 projects in Android Studio which both have 2 different string files for 2 languages. While in the one project a missing translation of a string resource is immediately highlighted in the other this is not done. How can I indicate missing translation also in the other project?

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Ensure that `resConfig` is well configured on the second project’s `build.gradle` file of your app module. If both projects support the same set of languages you can copy the `resConfig` line to the second project.

Comment: Thanks Shlomi for your answer. Basically I could not find any resConfig entry in any of the build.grandle files of both projects (I searched for it in the build.grandle files)

Comment: Interesting! Maybe the lint worked automatically somehow. Anyway, the `resConfigs` is where you declare the languages you support. For example if you support English, Spanish and French, you need to add `resConfigs “en”, “es”, “fr”` to the `defaultConfig` section. Please try to add it (with your actual locales of course) and try again.

Comment: Thanks Shlomi for your answer. Basically I did what you said for the one project and it worked (but I did not do it for the other project as here there was no problem with the translations). If you want, you can post your comment as an answer and then I will accept and upvote it such that you get points.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, without `resConfigs` configured, you can build an APK, drag it to Android Studio and check if the correct `values-XX` folder exists.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel: I do not really understand your last comment. In the one project I do not have the resConfigs anywhere in the build.grandle file but - at least in the emulator - everything seems to work as it should. Also when switching the language everything in translated correctly.

Comment: Actually that answers the questions. I wondered if the resources are actually packed in the final APK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that resConfig is well configured on both projects’ `build.gradle` file of your app module. If both projects support the same set of languages you can copy the resConfig line to the second project.

For example if you support English, Spanish and French, you need to add resConfigs “en”, “es”, “fr” to the defaultConfig section.